# Callback to other client in a WCF scenario

Tags: c#, wcf, callback, client

I'm making a multiplayer game using WCF in c#. There are 2 Clients and one server.

My question is how to implement the following functionality:

ClientA calls server and server Calls ClientB as a callback? is it possible?

What I am trying to do is when ClientA sends message to server server delivers it to ClientB as a callback or whatever way possible.

Answer (score 1):

> ClientA calls server and server Calls ClientB as a callback? is it possible?

Yes. It is done by programming.

A gets the message and determines where to forward it. All clients are connected by bidirectional channels to the server, so the server CAN forward the message to B.